# Sending a POST in Perl using Net::HTTP

Tags: perl, post

I've been looking through documentation for this, but I can't seem to find the answers to my questions. I'm trying to POST some data to a url using Net::HTTP in my perl script. The problem is, I need to be able to modify the headers (like add proxy information) for the request.

Does anyone have a simple example of something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a POST request using `Net::HTTP`, but as ikegami indicated, most people use [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) for this sort of thing.

```
my $http = Net::HTTP->new('Host' => "stackoverflow.com")
    or die "Unable to connect: $@";
$http->write_request('POST' => "/",
    'User-Agent' => "Mozilla/4.0",
    "foo=bar",
);
my ($code, $message, %h) = $http->read_response_headers;
if($code != 200) {
    die "Request failed: $message";
}
my $response;
while(1) {
    my $buf;
    my $n = $http->read_entity_body($buf, 1024);
    die "Read failed: $!" unless defined $n;
    last unless $n;

    $response .= $buf;
}
print "$response\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple example. If I were to add more headers (ie, proxy info), would that go in the hash passed to `write_request`?

Comment: @MaxMackie Yes any additional headers would go where the user-agent is (after the URL and before the data).

Comment: You should use HTTP::Request::Common's `POST` to build the headers and the payload.

Answer (score 0):

Most people send a post through Net::HTTP as follows:

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw( );

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $ua->post($url, [
   foo => 123,
   bar => 546,
]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on a system that doesn't have access to LWP, so I have to use the lower-level Net::HTTP. I'd install the module if I could...